# Is there any way to detect that from which activity the current activity is invoked without sending any parameter in intent?

Tags: android

Let suppose I have 3 activities say A,B and C now If I started activity C from A.So is there any way to find out in C that from which activity C is invoked.

Note: Without sending any parameter in intent.

Comment: You can try `getCallingActivity()` but this will probably only work if you call your 2nd activity with `startActivityForResult()`.

Answer (score 0):

> AFAIK, not possible without adding extras to the intent unless until you start the activity using `startActivityForResult`.

If you use `startActivityForResult`, you can get the parent activity reference as below using `getCallingActivity()`, otherwise you might want to add extras to the intent you use to start the activity

```
ComponentName parentActivity = getCallingActivity();
```